Recursively instantiating the classes inside an object
I want to activate, via reflection automatically and recursively all the nested classes inside a class I am instantiating. Here is the template of what I am trying to do, but I do not know how to make the function. I know how to enumerate the members and create the instances, but then I do not know how to assign them to the inner subtypes. Here follows the scheme. I need to do that by reflecting, without making any changes inside the original class. Just activation of the objects inside, from outside. No code rewriting inside the class or adding various "new" inside the class, obviously
        void someCode()
    {
        Nest MyNest = new Nest();
        createInstancesOfAllClassesInside(MyNest);
    }

    void createInstancesOfAllClassesInside(object anyObj)
    {
        //How, using reflection ?
    }

    public class Nest
    {
        public class A
        {
            public class A1
            {
                public class A2
                {
                    public string x = "Activate me!";
                }
            }
        }
        public class B
        {
            public class B1
            {
            }
        }
        public string s = "Hello";
    }

To respond to comments: by activation, I mean "like if" the inner classes had been instantiated by a new(). Thank you!
I will add my (nonworking) attempt to far so it may make the problem clearer:
public void CreateInstancesOfAllClassesInside(object obj)
{
    var objType = obj.GetType();

    // Loop through all nested types inside the object's type
    foreach (Type nestedType in objType.GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
    {

        // Create an instance of the nested type
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(nestedType);

        // cant find something like: SetValue(obj, instance) to attach the object to its container !

        // Recursively call the function to instantiate nested classes inside this instance
        CreateInstancesOfAllClassesInside(instance);
    }

}


public void CreateInstancesOfAllClassesInside2(ref object obj)
{

    var objType = obj.GetType();

    // Loop through all nested types inside the object's type
    foreach (Type nestedType in objType.GetNestedTypes(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
    {
        // Create an instance of the nested type using its constructor
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(nestedType);

        // Recursively instantiate any further nested classes inside this instance
        CreateInstancesOfAllClassesInside2(ref instance);

        // Now invoke the constructor of the nested type to ensure proper initialization
        ConstructorInfo[] ctors = nestedType.GetConstructors();
        if (ctors.Length > 0)
        {
            ctors[0].Invoke(instance, (object[])null); // Call the constructor
        }

        // instances of nested classes do not appear in the object root!  :-(

    }

}

I created the instances but could not find a way to "SetValue", that is, to assign the generated instance (via activator) to the corresponding member.
Here is an example of a class that could need that treatment:
 public class _CONST
{
    public class FOLDERS_APP
    {
        public class POSTS
        {
            public const string FOLDER_POSTS_USERS = "somefolder1/";
            public const string FOLDER_PRO_POSTS_FROM_USERS = "somefolder2/";
            public const string FOLDER_FOR_IM_IN_POST = "somefolder3/";
            public const string FOLDER_ATTACH_TO_POSTS = "somefolder4/";
        }
        public class MANIFESTOS
        {
            public const string FOLDER_APPLICATION_MO = "somefolder5/";
            public const string FOLDER_FOM_S = "somefolder6/";
        }
    }
}

In this case, when instantiating the main class, the inner classes are not instantiated. My goal is to instantiate them too [without editing the class and adding instantiators] because I need them for the serialization process. Or else the serializer will not consider them (they would be skipped). That is my constants would not be sent to the client, only those on the outer class (say the first level of the constants I am sending).

Can you precisely describe what createInstancesOfAllClassesInside is supposed to do here? Is it supposed to create new instances of all the classes shown? One for each class? What does it do with these instances? Surely you don't want to just discard them?

Please [edit] your question to include a description what you mean by "activate" or "activation" in this context. Also explain where/how you want to "assign" these instances, there are no fields/properties to save any references.

This is going to be a large tree of hundreds of constants that I need to serialize over the web from server to client side. Since each class contains many constants I need each of the inner classes to be actual instantiated objects so that the JSON serializer can work. Is it more clear now ?

Sounds X-Y-ish.

@Jada That sounds like an XY problem. Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the actual problem you have and what you are trying to do.

@ Sweeper It should render the nested classes inside the object as if they were instantiated with new(), Since new() on the Nest object does not automatically instantiate them.

How would you do that? There are no members of the respective types. There is nothing to assign to.

Better describe what your actual requirement is, then we can find a solution. As is, this is unanswerable outside of "that won't fly".

@ Progman as explained this is a nested structure of constants that I want to serialize. However, the web serializer requires "objects". The Nest is an object, but the classes inside would need a separate new() to become objects. So I want to use reflection to activate the inner classes. Got it :-) ?

@Jada You can create instances via reflection as well, but it is not clear if that would help you here in any way. Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the problem you have.

@Progman Sure, I added my (wrong) code attempt but should be useful to see my goal. I arrived to generate the instances, but I am missing how to assign them to the corresponding members. In practice, I need the SetValue() for the instance, but I can't find it, or something equivalent. Thank you!

@Jada You can't find any properties because there aren't any to find. The approach you are trying to implement is most likely the wrong way for the actual problem you have (that's called "XY problem"). You should [edit] your question to include a detailed description of the actual problem you try to solve. What you are trying to do right now most likely doesn't make any sense or will help you in any way.

The actual problem is simple. Imagine you have an object. Inside this object, there is another class, which is not instantiated by the parent class. Now when you instantiate the parent class as usual with new(), the inner class is not instantiated obviously. My goal is to use reflection to instantiate it. And in general, do that for any nested structure of them. Is it more clear now ?

@Jada Are you looking for Type.GetNestedTypes() to find all the class types defined inside another parent class?

@Progman Sure I find the classes. Instantiate them and I need to assign them to the corresponding member in the class (this is where I got stuck). After that one would add recursion too, which is easy. However, my main issue is that I do not know how to assign the newly activated instances to the corresponding members. I am missing 1 line in practice (the SetValue()). After that, it's all easy!

@Jada There is no "corresponding member" in any class, so you can't assign anything. Again, you should focus on the problem at the serializer and what the problem is there about "skipping them". There are no fields or properties in the classes you have shown (besides Nest.s and Next.A.A1.A2.x) which could be set/changed.

@Progman Apparently the serializer [System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer] requires actual (instantiated) objects (no static, no modules) or will raise an exception. That is the problem I am trying to work around!  :-)

A serializer probably only serializes properties, not const fields

I think you have a misunderstanding of how the classes you describe actaully work.
When you do
public class A {
    public class B {
    }
}

If you create an A object, it does not "contain" a B object property (in only has a type defined within its namespace), so there is no property to assign a new object to.
If you want A to actually _containaB` then you have to add a property:
public class A {
    public class B {
    }

    public B B {get; set;} = new B(); // for example only; using the same property name as the type will cause problems
}

Note that the B property is assigned a B object at initialization. You could use reflection externally to see that A has a B property and assign it a new B, but you can't do that with your current structure because the classes does not have properties that can be assigned, only nested types.

That is right, in fact in my code you can see I am getting the types: if (member is Type && ((Type)member).IsNested), and those get correctly picked and even instantiated using the activator(). The only problem is I am missing the command to attach them to the object  :-) For Fields for instance we have the SetValue, but for these instances ? I am missing, say, the corresponding "setValue" :--)

If there is no specific command, probably those objects newly instantiated (by activator()) based on the nested class definitions could be dynamically attached to the object anyway (System.Reflection.Emit), but I am not sure how to proceed to do that ...

I thank you all for your time and patience. If I find a way to attach those activated instances to the objects I will let you know later. For now, I will accept the solution proposed. Thank you and happy coding!

Nesting the classes does not automatically nest the corresponding objects. Nesting the classes only affects how you can access a class. E.g. if you have two nested classes like this:
public class A
{
    public class B
    {
    }
}

...then you can instantiate class B like this: new A.B(). I.e., this nesting works similar to a nesting inside a namespace. It nests the types but it does not nest the objects.
What you need are nesting through properties:
public class ClassA
{
    public ClassB B { get; set; } = new ClassB();
}

public class ClassB
{
    public ClassC C { get; set; } = new ClassC();
}

public class ClassC
{
    public int Value { get; set; } = 42;
}

Creating a ClassA object will now automatically create a nested ClassB object having a nested ClassC object.
Now you can write this:
var a = new ClassA();
int value = a.B.C.Value; // ==> 42


You can also use static classes to store constants. Then there is no class to be instantiated.
public static class CONST
{
    public static class FOLDERS_APP
    {
        public static class POSTS
        {
            public static readonly string[] FOLDER_POSTS_USERS = ["Tim", "Sue"];
        }
    }
}


The nesting here has the purpose to make the constants look like:  _CONST.FOLDERS_APP.POSTS.FOLDER_POSTS_USERS  in the code, so they are intuitive and easy to use. All the nesting is just to group constants. My problem is that the serializer skips the inner classes if they have not been instantiated. Serialization is needed for the server and client to stay in sync. It saves a lot of work. This is all. Is it now more clear the intent?

I added an example with static classes. In my example with non-static classes you can just name your properties FOLDERS_APP. POSTS and FOLDER_POSTS_USERS instead of B, C and Value and you get what you want too.

Yes, that is fine. Thank you However, my problem is that I need for non static classes because there are more things and methods in the class that need to be used. Do you have a solution for the general case? And the real issue is that the serializer also requires an actual instance, or "object". Static or modules won't do.

Well, my example with the properties does exactly this. Where is the problem?

The problem is that the web serializer  System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer (refuses to process it if it is not an instance of an object. And I need to send my class of constants to the client side to be acquired by javascript with JSON.parse(). Is it more clear my goal ?

Again, this is exactly what my example with ClassA, ClassB and ClassC does! It creates nested objects.

Sure, that is correct, but my requirement was not to mess with the original class. Consider that I have a very large number of nested levels with hundreds of constants.  Clearly one wants no to touch that and just work on reflection to activate the inner classes. That would be an elegant solution. Of course, I start unpacking the classes and activating them separately I can do that but the hierarchical view of all constants is lost. For this reason, I specified that the original class should remain intact.  :-)

Maybe this is what you are looking for: C# deserialize JSON using JavaScriptSerializer.DeserializeObject.

Yes, that is the one I use, which will be deserialized by JavaScript on the client side. The problem is that apparently it only processes actual instantiated objects. Anyway, if you gurus do not find a way to set the new instance created in the object, at this point I will have to follow your indication and unpack the nested levels adding manually all the new(). I will wait a bit to see if the elegant solution I hope for appears, or else I will accept this solution. Thank you for all your kindness and time :-)

I get the feeling you are trying to use the wrong concept. What you need is an API definition and a versioned one at that. If your service uses constant values, make them known by documentation and contract.
